# adding bookmark removes equation citations

Tags: citing, bookmarks

After adding bookmark:

```
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

to my document, I receive warnings for 1) citing within subsubsection title, and 2) with all my equation citations which change to (??).

I'm using a specific documentclass of my school for writing my document. The 2 types of warnings are as follows:

1) Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line x.

2) LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:something' on page x undefined on input line y.

How should I resolve the problem(s)?

Thank you

Comment: A minimal example is needed.

Comment: @egreg How can I provide a minimal example when the documentclass is private?

Comment: And how can you hope somebody guesses right?

Comment: @egreg How can you reproduce the problem without  the document class? What is the minimum example in this case? \documentclass {X} ?

Comment: I've updated my answer after your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `\cite` in sectional titles can be solved by adding

```
\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\cite\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

to the document preamble (you lose the reference, but you wouldn't get it anyway, because in bookmarks macros cannot perform assignments, which are necessary for `\cite` to work). If you like to see the citation key, change

```
\let\cite\@gobble
```

into

```
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{[#1]}
```

The second issue is due to `cleveref` being loaded before `hyperref`.

Comment: Thank you. It resolved my problem. On the first issue: I have the reference in subtitle with \let\cite\@gobble.

Comment: @Elnaz The `hyperref` package does a good job in redefining common commands so that they can give an approximate representation in bookmarks, but doesn't tackle `\cite`; a different solution could be `\texorpdfstring{~\cite{key}}{}` in the title.