# Reference (\cite) in pdf bookmark

Tags: citing, bookmarks

In my current document I have quite a lot `\section` commands containing `\cite` commands. Using `hyperref` or `bookmark` (as shown in the mwe below), the pdf bookmarks just print the corresponding key rather than the number.

Output: chapter titleFirst

Desired output: chapter title [1]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{First,
author = {First, A.},
journal = {Journal},
pages = {1762--1776},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title\cite{First}}
\cite{First}
\end{document}
```

As the `\cite` command is not expandable, the desired output is not obtained. Is there instead any possibility to get access to the counter that corresponds to the key, so that one can use the `\texorpdfstring` method to print the number to the pdf bookmarks while using the normal `\cite` command in the .tex file?

Finally, I as well found the following possibility ([by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294894/134144)) that ensures, that the keys are not printed in the bookmarks, but as stated above, I would prefer to have the numbers in the bookmarks as well.

```
\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\cite\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I find cites in the bookmarks, in the table of contents and in chapter titles (do you really have a citation there?) quite unusual, even more if there are numeric. Imho it would be much better to suppress them in all these places.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Due to the guidelines that I have to stick to, thouse citations in chapter titles and in the table of contents are definitely required.

Comment: No guideline can force you to add a citation reference to a text that isn't a citation. So why don't you change the chapter titles so that this isn't needed? It seems odd anyway that you use citations as titles.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: As this guideline is strickly mandatory I can not simply ignore it. Changing chapter (or sectioning...) titles is not an option either as I have to follow certain rules for them as well. The citation itself does as well not refer to the title itself, but tells the reader that the experiment that is described in this chapter/section was done exactly as described by the reference that is cited. Although that may seem strange or wrong I have to keep this kind of format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are printing the bibliography you can add labels and then use \ref in the chapter titles:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\def\@currentlabel{\thefield{labelnumber}}\label{labelnumber-\thefield{entrykey}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title [\ref{labelnumber-herrmann}]}

\cite{doody}  \cite{herrmann}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]