# biblatex + hyperref: Show \textcite in PDF bookmark

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

**Update:** After Ulrike's comments I see that I ask the impossible. I might later re-write the question but I need time to ask a better question.

---

- I want to show some `biblatex` stuff in the PDF bookmarks which is a difficult thing to do.
- Luckily, I found [How can I make \citetitle work in a hyperref section bookmark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73678) and tried the two proposed answers.
- The idea of Heiko's answer is to store the result of a `biblatex` command and then reuse it in the `\section` etc. command. egreg's answer is good and I will use it for a smaller project but for a larger project, Heiko's solution would be beneficial.
- I tried to do the same thing with `\textcite` but failed, see below.
- **Question:** How to store the result of `\textcite` so that it can be reused in `\section` etc. and be also shown in the PDF bookmarks?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

% See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73678
% This is my own (not working) creation based on Heiko's code.
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myTextciteStore}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \global\let\myTextciteStore@Result\relax
    \textcite{#2}%
  \endgroup
  \let#1\myTextciteStore@Result
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{\textcite{padhye}}

% Does not work, it prints the citation actually.
\myTextciteStore\myTemp{padhye}

\section{\myTemp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Related

- [Reference (\cite) in pdf bookmark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390817)
- [How can I make \citetitle work in a hyperref section bookmark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73678)

Comment: you can't. textcite is a too complex, noexpandable command. You can only extract the fields you need with the method described in the other posting and then build from is a faked version. Personally I think that if would be easier to write the names manually. How often do you have a cite in a sectioning heading?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, thanks for the reply. In my case, there are about 40 instances.

Comment: Maybe one can write the result in an aux file and read it back in the next compilation cycle?

Comment: writing requires expansion too. That is the same problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer hmmm, ok. The textcite command works at least in the section and in the toc correctly. Problem is the bookmarks onky. Therefore I thought that this is feasible.

Comment: well look into the toc-file and see what it contains.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer will do later, it's 0545 in the morning for me right now and I need to get up :).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see your point :) `\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.1}\textcite {Kelsch2012}: \citetitle {Kelsch2012}}{23}{section.4.1}%`

Comment: The problem I have is that I'm not writing the citation commands manually so replacing them with the relevant details by hand isn't straightforward. I'm specifying a bibkey, but that is then doing a bunch of things which include, somewhere in the middle, writing the toc line. Pre-pandemic, I just didn't use hyperref ;). Mid-pandemic, I just let the bibkeys go into the bookmarks. So anything which improves on that is a plus. For me, that basically means `\citeauthor` and `\citetitle`. The former seems much more complex than the latter although I have a simplistic version.

Comment: @cfr Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637962.

Comment: @cfr See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637962/ for an answer from the **biblatex author**.